# JTextField changing border

Tags: java, java-7, jtextfield

How can I change the border color of JTextField? I tried `someField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED,2))`, but it is giving me

> mismatcherror(incompatible types: javafx.scene.paint.Color can not be converted to java.awt.Color).

Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: Import `java.awt.Color` instead of` javafx.scene.paint.Color`. These are two different user interface libraries and as such you must be sure to import the correct one for your use.

Comment: change import package of Color class to  java.awt.Color

Answer (score 2):

Please check your `import` section. You should import `java.awt.Color` like this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
```

If you want to create borders with the `LineBorder` class, then you can do:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

textField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
```

Another option is to create borders with the `BorderFactory` class, like this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code needs to refer to both `java.awt.Color` and  `javafx.scene.paint.Color` then you'll get another type of error if you try to import them both.

```
$ cat test.java
import java.awt.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
public class test {}

$ javac test.java
test.java:2: error: a type with the same simple name is already defined by the single-type-import of Color
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
^
1 error
```

A solution is to pick one to *not* import and then fully qualify the class wherever it's used in the referring class.

In your specific case, since your class file has already imported `javafx.scene.paint.Color`, you might already have code that refers to it.

The easiest thing to do is replace one import with another and if it compiles then you're done. Which means you did *not* have code that refers to `javaf.scene.paint.Color`.

But if it doesn't compile, then you should not import `java.awt.Color`. Instead, what you do is modify the first offending code to this:

```
someField.setBorder(new LineBorder(java.awt.Color.RED, 2));
```